# Typing image element with event listener in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I try typing the event as `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLImageElement>` to make the `e.target.src` work I get the following error in the imageFound and ImageNotFound:

> Type '(evt: React.ChangeEvent) => void' is not
> assignable to type 'EventListener'.
> Types of parameters 'evt' and 'evt' are incompatible.
> Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent'.

I was unable to find any solution to type this.

```
const imageFound = (e: any) => {
        e?.target?.src && found.push(e.target.src);
    };
    const imageNotFound = (e: any) => {
        window?.console && console.warn("Preload image failed!", e.target.src);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        let image: IImage;
            const img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener("load", imageFound);
            img.addEventListener("error", imageNotFound);
            img.src = getImageSrc(image.src);
        }
```

Comment: where are you invoking imageFound? add that snippet too

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your type definition to:

```
type HTMLImageEvent = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLImageElement> & Event
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vthqnc?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: similar error: Argument of type '(e: HTMLImageEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(e: HTMLImageEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'HTMLImageEvent'

Comment: I would need more context around how your code is structured to help you further.